# Python 3.8: z array size error in matplotlib.pyplot.contour

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib, contour

I am trying to plot multiple lines using numpy.meshgrid and matplotlib.pyplot.contour.

Like this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

l1 = [[1.14524340102759, 0.0, 0.876379777564501, 0.0774032782000112],
 [0.698164152459634, 0.0, 0.577238912623023, 0.0334322477435396],
 [1.56063241621204, 0.0, 1.12917068564018, 0.129171162657132],
 [0.925893720680833, 0.0, 0.733948881787323, 0.0541614422907881],
 [1.35667899082301, 0.0, 1.00744147250486, 0.102545387706258]]

l2 = [(-3.33066845080019, -11.5692204395060),
 (-3.20810804556752, -11.6038035434509),
 (-3.45285619481352, -11.5333428807513),
 (-3.26943397473207, -11.5866740435686),
 (-3.39180976091197, -11.5514432194779)]

for i, j in zip(l1, l2):
    
    x4, y4 = np.meshgrid(np.arange(i[2], i[0], 0.05),np.arange(i[1], i[3], 0.05))
    
    plt.contour(x4, y4, j[0] * (x4 - i[0]) + j[1] * (y4 - i[1]) , [0], linewidths = 0.5, colors = 'crimson')
```

But I am getting this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-f93f79730069> in <module>
      9     x4, y4 = np.meshgrid(np.arange(i[2], i[0], 0.05),np.arange(i[1], i[3], 0.05))
     10 
---> 11     plt.contour(x4, y4, j[0] * (x4 - i[0]) + j[1] * (y4 - i[1]) , [0], linewidths = 0.5, colors = 'crimson')

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py in contour(data, *args, **kwargs)
   2565 @_copy_docstring_and_deprecators(Axes.contour)
   2566 def contour(*args, data=None, **kwargs):
-> 2567     __ret = gca().contour(
   2568         *args, **({"data": data} if data is not None else {}),
   2569         **kwargs)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py in inner(ax, data, *args, **kwargs)
   1436     def inner(ax, *args, data=None, **kwargs):
   1437         if data is None:
-> 1438             return func(ax, *map(sanitize_sequence, args), **kwargs)
   1439 
   1440         bound = new_sig.bind(ax, *args, **kwargs)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py in contour(self, *args, **kwargs)
   6330     def contour(self, *args, **kwargs):
   6331         kwargs['filled'] = False
-> 6332         contours = mcontour.QuadContourSet(self, *args, **kwargs)
   6333         self._request_autoscale_view()
   6334         return contours

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\contour.py in __init__(self, ax, levels, filled, linewidths, linestyles, hatches, alpha, origin, extent, cmap, colors, norm, vmin, vmax, extend, antialiased, nchunk, locator, transform, *args, **kwargs)
    814         self._transform = transform
    815 
--> 816         kwargs = self._process_args(*args, **kwargs)
    817         self._process_levels()
    818 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\contour.py in _process_args(self, corner_mask, *args, **kwargs)
   1428             self._corner_mask = corner_mask
   1429 
-> 1430             x, y, z = self._contour_args(args, kwargs)
   1431 
   1432             _mask = ma.getmask(z)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\contour.py in _contour_args(self, args, kwargs)
   1486             args = args[1:]
   1487         elif Nargs <= 4:
-> 1488             x, y, z = self._check_xyz(args[:3], kwargs)
   1489             args = args[3:]
   1490         else:

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\contour.py in _check_xyz(self, args, kwargs)
   1519             raise TypeError(f"Input z must be 2D, not {z.ndim}D")
   1520         if z.shape[0] < 2 or z.shape[1] < 2:
-> 1521             raise TypeError(f"Input z must be at least a (2, 2) shaped array, "
   1522                             f"but has shape {z.shape}")
   1523         Ny, Nx = z.shape

TypeError: Input z must be at least a (2, 2) shaped array, but has shape (1, 3)
```

I had a similar problem with another set of lists I was plotting, but the problem there was my xmin and xmax values were in the wrong place in the meshgrid. But that does not seem to be the problem here. So I cannot understand what exactly I'm doing wrong.

Please help.

Comment: The problem is that `np.arange(i[1], i[3], 0.05)` has too few points. You might try `x4, y4 = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(i[2], i[0], 50), np.linspace(i[1], i[3], 50))`.

Comment: That number is not the number of points. It is like a step-size. The smaller the number, the more solid or fine the line appears. tomjin was able to identify the problem. You can check the answer below ;)

Comment: That's why I suggested `linspace` instead of `arange`. Sometimes `arange` gives too few values, some too many.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is the second element of list `l1`

```py
[0.698164152459634, 0.0, 0.577238912623023, 0.0334322477435396],
```

The final element of this array `0.0334` is less than the step size you use in your `np.arange` call here

```py
np.arange(i[1], i[3], 0.05))
```

which if we fill in the values

```py
>>> np.arange(0.0, 0.0334322477435396, 0.05)
array([0.])
```

This doesn't happen for any of the other entries in `l1`. Fix that (e.g. by setting the step size to be smaller than that value) and it will fix your problem.